# jQuery UI -> handling dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use a dynamic, single dialog that changes based on ajax calls. Is there any elegant way to change the height and width based on the new content? Currently, I have an empty div which is filled, causing problems.

Help?

Comment: Empty div which is filled? Don't understand you ...

Comment: I have an empty div. An ajax call is made which returns data. This data populates the div.

Comment: dialog as in real browser window (from window.open or window.showModalDialog) or a made up in page dialog (based on div)?

Comment: Normally, the div will be rendered according to the contents inside when it is loaded. Is there a reason to set the width and height manually?

Comment: I need a single div that resizes based on the content assigned to it. Manually setting height/width is a pain in the ass and a burden to the user. Is there no better way to do this? And of course, it's a jqueryui dialog based on a div. Look at the tags on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't pull up the dialog until you have data, you should be fine.